# Teradata SQL - select distinct returning duplicate rows where one row has null values

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I'm stuck on query where i'm joining multiple tables to bring in attributes I need for a specific primary key. What I'm finding is I'm receiving duplicate rows, which are essentially the same, but one row has null (?) values in a few columns. I only want to return the row with populated data.

I've checked all of my vol tables up to this point and there are no duplicates and I have the same distinct row count until my final vol table. I am joining in new data from other tables in the final vol table, and will post that query, but just curious if anyone knows why this would happen with "SELECT DISTINCT".

I tried using a clause "WHERE PROD_LN IS NOT NULL", but I have some that are not duplicates and will not have values for PROD_LN. I was also thinking of trying a "CASE WHEN PROD_LN IS NULL THEN PROD_LN = PROD_LINE NOT NULL" but not sure if that would work. Any help is appreciated!

```
        ACCT_NAME | GRP_ID   |  GRP_B  | ASGND_CD | PROD_LN | PROD_TYP | PLCY_TYP | FINCL | MKT_SGMT |
    ENTERPRISE A  | 00012345 |  N12345 |    1     |    ?    |     ?    |     8    |   ?   |     ?    |
    ENTERPRISE A  | 00012345 |  N12345 |    1     |    H    |   SPPO   |     8    |  ASO  |    AFG   |
```

Comment: Can you provide the SQL statement you are using that produces these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number() over (partition by ACCT_NAME, GRP_ID, GRP_B, ASGND_CD
                           order by prod_ln nulls last
                          ) = 1;
```

I am guessing that by duplicate, you mean on the first four columns.  In any case, the `partition by` should be the columns that you want to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will this return ONLY the rows where nulls don't exist or all, but sorted by nulls at the end?

Comment: @CGermain . .. This will return one row for each combination of values in the `partition by` column.  That row will have `prod_ln` not `NULL`, if possible.  Otherwise, the row will have a `NULL` value in that column.